# Memory alloc failure handling in void function

Tags: c, memory-management

I just wanted to know the way of handling the memory allocation failure in void function

e.g:-

```
    void func()
    {
      struct stack *p;
      p = malloc(sizeof(struct stack));
      if(p == NULL)
      {
        /*here is where my confusion is,I cant return as the function is of 
type void, and I have to do the mem check compulsorily. */

      }

    }
```

Comment: Well, what do you want to happen if it fails to allocate memory?

Comment: Since,It is a huge program, I just need to ensure their is no dereference of pointer and no crash

Comment: You can use `return;` to return any time from a function returning `void`.

Comment: Ya,I am aware that in void function, return is not possible. I just want to know the way the memory allocation can be checked and appropriate action to be taken in case if allocation fails

Comment: Though, generally speaking, silently swallowing allocation failures is never a good idea.

Comment: @Sanman Right. It can be checked, and *you're already checking it*. The part you're stuck on is "take appropriate action if it fails", because you can't figure out what an appropriate action is. (And that's not purely a programming problem, by the way)

Answer (score 2):

If the memory allocation fails you can use the return statement.

> In void returning functions, you cannot return the values, But you can use the  empty return statement.

So you can use like this, after the call of `malloc`.

```
if ( p == NULL ) {
      printf("Memory allocation failed\n");
      return;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If function type is void also , you can return from function. use

```
return;
```

ie, no return value. just returning from the point you want to return.

In your case

```
void func()
{
  struct stack *p;
  p = malloc(sizeof(struct stack));
  if(p == NULL)
  {
    printf("memory allocation failed\n");
    return; //just return

  }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

`return ;  //called as empty return statement.`

can be used for functions with a return type of `void`.

In your code, after malloc just use

```
return ;
```

Answer (score -1):

you can use atexit:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void functionA ()
{
   printf("This is functionA not able to allocate the memory\n");
}


 void func()
    {
      struct stack *p;
      atexit(functionA );
      p = malloc(sizeof(struct stack));
      if(p == NULL)
      {
exit ( 0 );
}

return ( 0 );
}
```

Comment: Before exit it will call functionA .